# Is there a problem with this code? I can't get it to work. Help me PLEASE

Tags: c++, function, pointers

The purpose is to sort, display, and average out scores input by the user.
I haven't been able to figure it out yet.
If you have solved this, please help.
So far, I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void sortArr(int [], int);
void getAvg(const int [], int);

int main()
{
    int *scorePtr = nullptr;
    int size;

    cout << "Enter the number of test scores: ";
    cin >> size;
    while(size < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Enter the number of scores: ";
        cin >> size;
    }
    if(size == 0)
    {
        cout << "No scores. Terminating program...";
        return 0;
    }

    scorePtr = new int[size];

    cout << "Enter the scores earned on each test: ";
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cin >> scorePtr[index];
        while(scorePtr[index] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Entry not valid. Enter score #" << (index + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> scorePtr[index];
        }
    }

    sortArr(scorePtr, size);
    getAvg(scorePtr, size);

    return 0;
}

void sortArr(int *arr[], int SIZE)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    int *minElem;

    for(startScan = 0; startScan < (SIZE - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = arr[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
            if(*(arr[index]) < *minElem)
            {
                minElem = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minElem;
    }
    cout << "Here are the scores you entered, sorted in ascending order: " << endl;
    for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        cout << *(arr[count]) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void getAvg(const int arr[], int Size)
{
    double total = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int index = 0; index < Size; index++)
    {
        total += arr[index];
    }
    avg = (total/Size);
    cout << "Your average score is: " << avg << endl;
}
```

All I get from this code is a compiler error.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Please and thank you.

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: I tried searching around but couldn't find what I need.

Comment: You need to extract a [mcve] and include that along with the error message in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, your declaration of `sortArr()` does not match the definition.

The Declaration:

```cpp
void sortArr(int [], int);
```

The Definition:

```cpp
void sortArr(int *arr[], int SIZE) {...}
```

As you see, the definition says that `sortArr()` takes parameters of an array of `int`s,  and a `int`. However, your definition says that `sortArr()` takes a parameters of an array of `int*`s and an `int`. The compiler concludes that they must be different functions.

When the compiler tries to compiler, it goes with your declaration, but can't find the definition. You can do what the others did to fix it, which I will also list here:

Firstly, change the declaration of `sortArr()` to

```cpp
void sortArr(int*, int);
```

An `int[]` can be converted to a `int*`, so this is what we need.

Next, go to the definition of `sortArr()`, and change this. (The comments explain why)

```cpp
void sortArr(int* arr, int SIZE) //we only need a pointer, as it is basically the same thing as an array
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    int minElem; //if minElem was a pointer, it would get overwritten every time by arr, so use a regular int

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (SIZE - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = arr[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
            if (arr[index]/*No need for dereferencer here, because indexing already dereferences.*/ < minElem)
            {
                minElem = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minElem;
    }
    cout << "Here are the scores you entered, sorted in ascending order: " << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        cout << arr[count] << " "; //Again, no dereferencing here because we are using the [] operator
    cout << endl;
}
```

I have tested this code against multiple cases, and it works. Hopefully this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You defined `sortArr` as taking an array of pointers to int for its argument, but you passed it an actual array of `int`.  It sounds like the latter is what you actually want, so you need to rewrite `sortArr` to work properly on an array of `int`, starting with changing the definition to

```
void sortArr(int arr[], int SIZE) {
...
}
```

without the `*`.  This also means that most of the `*` dereferences in that function will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To add on top of Nate's answer, pass a pointer to an array to `sortArr` . Compiler "converts" an array to a pointer.

```
void sortArr(int* arr, int SIZE) {
...
}
```

Also there are more finer ways to check for input errors. Use to your hearts content

```
while(!(cin >> size) || size < 0 || size == 0)
{
// Error message
cin.clear();
// A huge constant
cin.ignore(999,'\n');
}
```